# How to create collision shapes for SVG in Forge2D using Flame?

Tags: flutter, svg, flame, forge2d

I am working on a Flutter project, utilizing the Flame game engine and the Forge2D library for physics simulation. I need to add collisions for my SVG elements in the game. I already know how to render SVG in Flame, but I am unsure about how to create collision shapes for SVG in Forge2D. Is there a way to create collision shapes based on SVG? Any examples or recommendations would be very helpful.

Thank you!

I tried to find SvgShape but I didn't find it

```
@override
  Body createBody() {
    final shape = CircleShape();
    shape.radius = size.x;

    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(
      shape,
      userData: this, 
      restitution: 1,
      density: 15,
      friction: 1,
    );

    final bodyDef = BodyDef(
      position: initialPosition,
      angle: 0,
      type: BodyType.dynamic,
      gravityScale: Vector2.all(3.5),
    );
    return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
  }
}
```

Comment: A shape has an outline/stroke. That outline has points. You can test if any point on that outline is close to any other point on any other outline in the SVG. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInStroke could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately nothing built-in to do this, and Forge2D also only support convex shapes.

A lot of SVGs wouldn't be supported either since only rectangles, polygons and circle shapes are supported, so it couldn't support arc curves and paths for example.